# Session lost in few seconds randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables, session-timeout

My web application is developed using Dot Net 4.0 C# and MS SQL 2008 R2. Application and Database are deployed on separate servers.

I have used form authentication on my application and user session is maintained in Session object. Recently the session object on my application was getting lost frequently because of no reason.

I've tried below stuffs to fix this, but nothing worked.

1. Increase the session timeout from web.config
2. Increase the IDLE Timeout of Application Pool from IIS
3. Set the number of Worker Process to 1
4. Proper exception handling for required method and global exception handling
5. Fixed all exceptions and memory leakage.

Because of some other reason we've restarted our SQL Server Machine today and everything started working perfect now.

I'm confused now on how can a InProc session issue be solved by restarting SQL Server machine.

Comment: How did you determine that session was lost?

Comment: Whenever I try to access the session value it returns null

Comment: Maybe it was never non-null. The symptom of lost session is that you set it, _you retrieve a non-null value_, then some time later when you retrieve it, you get null. Be absolutely sure you are using the same key in both places. Not `Session["key"] = "1";` then `var x = Session["kiy"];`

Comment: Thanks John. But I've checked every scenario mentioned above and in fact the key also. If I'm accessing the wrong key it would have not ran for first few seconds.